# Understanding the Android suggested screen size buckets documentation

Tags: android, screen, dimension

I am trying to understand the *suggested* screen size buckets but I am very confused by the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document.

In the document they declare two different set of dimensions for the *suggested* screen size buckets.

The first set of dimensions:

> **Range of screens supported**
>
> As you design your UI for different screen sizes, you'll discover that each design requires a minimum amount of space. So, each generalized screen size above has an associated minimum resolution that's defined by the system. These minimum sizes are in "dp" units—the same units you should use when defining your layouts—which allows the system to avoid worrying about changes in screen density.
>
> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

And a second set of dimensions:

> **Configuration examples**
>
> To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:
>
> 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
> 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
> 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
> 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

- Why are there two sets of dimensions given?
- Why does the first set appear to have the width and height reversed?

Thanks!

Comment: "Why are there two sets of dimensions given?" -- the second set are examples, not definitions of the classic screen size buckets. "Why does the first set appear to have the width and height reversed?" -- because that is the way they wrote the Web page.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. It is a bit bizarre that they would randomly reverse width and height for this set of dimensions, when they are not reversed anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to the world of documentation bugs! :-) Lots of 'em in the Android developer docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two sets of dimensions are two very different ways to reference screen size.

The buckets in the first set that you posted (xlarge, large, normal, small) are actual screen size buckets. They are not just shorthand ways of referring to the sizes listed in your second set. You can create `layout-xlarge` and `layout-small` folders for your resources, and those will be automatically loaded for devices that fit the description for those buckets.

The next thing to note is that using the above buckets [is discouraged as of Android 3.2 and up](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). Those buckets were made obsolete by the addition of the ability to declare resources for a specific density.

For example, you can now create a `layout-sw320dp` that will be used for all devices that have a smallest screen width of 320dp. This allows for much more flexibility and better control over how your layouts are used. The second set of dimensions that you listed is intended as a guide to help you decide which folders to create using the new `sw<N>dp`, `w<N>dp`, and `h<N>dp` resource qualifiers.

Finally, notice that the values actually do line up. The second value in each dimension in your first set is the width of that particular screen. The second set is helping you choose a *smallest width* size for your resource qualifiers. The "smallest width" is simply the smallest dimension for the screen regardless of the device's physical orientation.

Comment: Thanks @Tanis.7x. So, size buckets have been deprecated but the "suggested" resource qualifiers are also measured in 'dp' and  align with the old size buckets. Which makes sense as there must be a common set of "breakpoints" when analyzing all the different devices on the market. Android does an excellent job of making this confusing in the documentation. It could have been broken into a pre 3.2 section and a post 3.2 section. The confusion is furthered by referring to the "suggested" resource qualifier sizes in the `Dashboard - Screen Sizes and Densities` section.